# ASP: Time picker

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was using a time picker which returns the date and time together. This was making for me problems since i am comparing this value with a database column of type `time` only. Tried another free `time picker control` but when assigning it to a `repeater` and when it comes to define the data source of repeater and writting the `SQL` Query I cant select the time picker control from the drop down list simply because it is not available.

any other time picker controls with a stylish look and effecient?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a control which fits your exact needs but you should be able to convert the .net DateTime to a TimeSpan which you could then compare against the sql Time datatype

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(myDateTime.Hour, myDateTime.Minute, myDateTime.Second, myDateTime.Millisecond);
```